# Getting dataset refreshes as admin through Power BI REST API with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, rest, powerbi, powerbi-api

I have a Power BI workspace with GUID [`$group`] and in it there is a dataset with GUID [`$dataset`]. From the Azure Cloud Shell I can run the following code:

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount
# I log in with my personal credentials
$Url = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/' + $group + '/datasets/' + $dataset + '/refreshes?$top=3'
$results = $(Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $Url -Method Get | ConvertFrom-Json).value
```

This works fine and I get the last 3 refresh events, but I would like to modify the previous code so that it does not only work for my workspaces, but for all the workspaces of the tenant. We have a system in place so that I can get the required credentials and then connect through a service principal as follows:

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $Credentials -Tenant $TenantId
```

Now that I am connected through the service principal, if I try to run again

```
$Url = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/' + $group + '/datasets/' + $dataset + '/refreshes?$top=3'
$results = $(Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $Url -Method Get | ConvertFrom-Json).value
```

I get the error message:

```
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod: One or more errors occurred. ({
  "code": "ItemNotFound",
  "message": "Couldn't find dataset id "
})
```

I have tried to identify the problem going down from groups to datasets to refreshes. I have found that the string '/admin' is required in the url for this to work, and in fact if I run

```
$Url = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups/'+$group+'/datasets'
$results_datasets = $(Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $Url -Method Get | ConvertFrom-Json).value
```

I get the datasets of my workspace. However, I cannot go "further down" than datasets! Let me explain. I can check that

```
$dataset -in $results_datasets.id
# True
```

But when I try to replace the url with one of the following

```
$Url = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups/' + $group + '/datasets/' + $dataset
$Url = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups/' + $group + '/datasets/' + $dataset + '/refreshes'
$Url = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups/' + $group + '/datasets/' + $dataset + '/refreshes?$top=3'
```

I always get the error message

```
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod: One or more errors occurred. ({
  "code": "",
  "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://wabi-europe-north-b-redirect.analysis.windows.net/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups/[$group]/datasets/[$dataset etc]'."
})
```

Why does this work until datasets and stops working further down?
Is there a better way to get the refreshes data through a service principal?

P.S.: both 'Allow service principals to use Power BI APIs' and 'Dataset Execute Queries REST API' are enabled for the security group of the service principal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see there is no **admin** API returning refreshes for dedicated dataset in given group.

You an try this one, but this is NOT **admin** one.
[https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/datasets/{datasetId}/refreshes](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/datasets/%7BdatasetId%7D/refreshes)

Please see more details under this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-refresh-history-in-group

You can also read this discussion where you can find similar case like your one.
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Service/Unable-to-retrieve-dataset-refresh-history/m-p/2820487